# Nomencl and nomenclature in included PDF

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdfpages, nomenclature, nomencl

I'm desperate and have searched everywhere and tried many different things, but do not seem to find the solution to my problem...

I'm writing a thesis which has some PDF's included (published articles) and I'm currently doing the Nomenclature of my thesis using the nomencl package.
In the list of symbols I want the symbol, description, unit and page (with link).  So here are the problems I'm having:

1. I have some symbols inside the PDF which I would like to include in the general list of nomenclature (using the command \nomenclature[]{}{}) with links to the pages. 
   Using the \nomenclature command before the \includepdf command will come as if the symbol is in the first page of the pdf or on the page after the last
   Is there anyway to trick or force a page number in nomencl?
2. I would like that the text in the long descriptions of the nomenclature list do not go until the end of the line in the 1st line (see image below - the of should not go until the end of the line...

The following code can serve as an example

Thank you very much in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ifthen} %for parameter changes in nomencl package
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\makenomenclature

\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\vspace{0.5in}} %vertical spacing between title and list

\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\dotfill\hyperpage{#1}} %pagenumber in nomenclature + link

\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{ [#1]} %activate units

\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{% divide nomenclature into groups
  \ifthenelse{%
    \equal{#1}{A}%
  }{%
  \item[\textbf{Symbols}]%

  }{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Acronyms}]%

    }{}%
  }%
} 
\begin{document}

\printnomenclature[2cm] %generate the nomenclature 
\cleardoublepage

\section{Introduction}

This is $A$ and this is $Z$ while this is an ACRONYM.
\nomenclature[A]{$A$}{Normal description\nomunit{\si{\atomicmassunit}}}%
\nomenclature[A]{$Z$}{Kind of a very very very very very very very long description of a symbol \nomunit{\si{\metre\squared\per\gram\squared\micro\coulomb}}}%
\nomenclature[B]{ACRONYM}{Meaning of the acronym}%

\cleardoublepage
\nomenclature[A]{$r$}{Symbol in page 3 of the article}%
\nomenclature[B]{AA}{Acronym in page 2 of the article}%
\includepdf[pagecommand={},pages=-]{4pageArticle.pdf} %article with 4 pages

\end{document}
```

[image: Code result (page 1)]

[image: Code result (page 2)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have many acronyms then you can edit the *.nls file directly, the page reference is i nthe `\nompageref{}` in the end of each item.

The nomencl package calls `\pagedeclaration` and writes that to the glossary file, section 5.3 of the `nomencl` documentation gives an example of this call. You could define a command that would add page definition to the `\@@@nomenclature` command in a style file.

As for the second question, I would suggest simply using shorter descriptions, but if you must use long ones then you could add `\\` where you'd like the line break (here it would be before the 'of').

Also, consider moving to `glossaries` package, you could use longtable nomenclature that would not need manual breaking.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to add the entries  manually to the *.nls file since they are not so many anyway.

I use the nomecl package because for me is much more convenient just to declare each symbol in the text, instead of defining it in the preamble and then put on the text. But I will consider it for the future.

Regarding the paragraphs your solution works.

Thank you once again.